# how to move a text to the right side of the page

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to move the navbar contents to the right side of the page but it's not aligning with the navbar title.

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica;
}
header li {
    list-style: none;
    float: right;
    display: inline;
    padding: 20px;
   padding-left:3px;
}
header {
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
   box-shadow: 0 1px 8px #ddd;
  
}
```

```html
<header>
<h1> Dev101 </h1>
  <nav>
 <ul>
          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
 </ul>
  </nav>
 </header>
```

Comment: hello. it is not clear what result you want to see. please give more explanations

Comment: I want the "Contact, services, and about" to line up with the "dev101" logo, instead of being below it.

Comment: just add `display: flex` to the css for `header {}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a flex to the header:

```
header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 8px #ddd;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `float`. `float`'s are deprecated. In order for `justify-content: space-between;` to work you need to use `display: flex;` on the same element.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica;
}

header li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline;
  padding: 20px;
  padding-left: 3px;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 8px #ddd;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1> Dev101 </h1>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Without using any **padding** , basically **making** it **responsive** , try to **avoid** using **px** in your websites as it is not good for responsiveness .

Instead **use** **%** , **rem** , **em** .

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica;
}

header li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline;
}
header li a{
  text-decoration: none;
}
header li a:hover{
  text-decoration: underline;
}
 

header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 8px #ddd;
}
header nav{
  width:40%;
}
header nav ul{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1> Dev101 </h1>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `float` to align nav to the right

HTML:

```
<header>
  <h1>Dev101</h1>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

CSS:

```
nav {
   float: right;
}
```